# Errors thrown from here are not handled

Tags: ios, json, swift, swift3

I've got this problem trying to parse a JSON on my iOS app:

Relevant code:

```
let jsonData:NSDictionary = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: urlData! as Data, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers ) as! NSDictionary

/* XCode error ^^^ Errors thrown from here are not handled */
```

Could anybody help me ?

Comment: And if you are using Swift 3, use Swift 3 types. Use `Data`, not `NSData`. Use `Error`, not `NSError`. Use Swift arrays and dictionaries, not `NSArray` and `NSDictionary`.

Comment: And do what the error messages tells you to do. You're using `try` but it's not into a proper Do-Catch scope...

Comment: try using try? and also add the code to your question

Comment: ... and do **not** load data synchronously.

Answer (score 122, accepted):

A possibly thrown error in `let jsonData = try JSONSerialization ...` is not handled.

You can ignore a possible error, and crash as penalty if an error occurs:

```
let jsonData = try! JSONSerialization ...
```

or return an `Optional`, so `jsonData` is `nil` in error case:

```
let jsonData = try? JSONSerialization ...
```

or you can catch and handle the thrown error:

```
do {
    let jsonData = try JSONSerialization ...
    //all fine with jsonData here
} catch {
    //handle error
    print(error)
}
```

You might want to study [The Swift Language](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ErrorHandling.html)

Comment: You deserved an up vote! I'm new to Swift! Oh man, Swift is a pain in the ass at first! <3

Comment: Another possibility: Inside a throwing function f, you can call another throwing function g without using "try". If g throws an error, f returns immediately and throws the same error.